# Under what circumstances will the serial number of a volume change?

Tags: partitioning

Under what circumstances will the serial number of a volume change? I know that the number is created when the partition is created, but will altering the size, creating a new partition in a different area of the disk), resizing the partition, formatting the partition, or anything else short of deleting and recreating the partition change this number?